# How to send some file contents and information about the data to a REST API and fetch it using node.js or express.js?

Tags: node.js, json, express, http-headers

I have a requirement where in I have to send contents of a file to a REST API endpoint along with some information about the data being sent. For example, assume I would like to send ~64KB of file data in a request:

1. Offset of the data in the file
2. Length of the data being sent
3. Some one or more strings like "truncate", "append", "overwrite" (called as flags)
4. Actual file content

I am thinking of sending offset, length, and flags (as strings) as JSON data and the actual file data in raw binary format. Is it an appropriate way to do or not? If possible can you share sample code on how to access the offset, length, flags, and file data received on server side when using node.js or express.js?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send a file using formdata and of course you can add there as many non-file fields as you want

Comment: @Anatoly, it's not straight forward send file case but only partial content of the file in a request. So, is using form data sufficient in this case?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on file fields? I don't know about such ones.